# How to replace a pattern in script using sed in-place inside the script

Tags: bash, sed

Below is my test script in which i am try to replace one of the line in script during runtime.

/home/xxx/test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`/`basename $0`
username=admin
password='pass1234'

u="$(grep 'username' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"
p="$(grep 'password' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"

sed -i "s/user=/user="${u}"/3" "$SCRIPT_PATH"
sed -i "s/pass=/pass="${p}"/3" $SCRIPT_PATH

user=
pass=
```

Issue: the sed is actually replacing the search pattern here. I tried "3" at the end hoping it will target the 3rd occurance in the file, but that didn't working as expected.

I want to to replace the last user=  and  pass=   with user=admin  and pass='pass1234'

Any advice. Still trying.

OUTPUT i expect the file should changed to:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`/`basename $0`
username=admin
password='pass1234'

u="$(grep 'username' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"
p="$(grep 'password' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"

sed -i "s/user=/user="${u}"/3" "$SCRIPT_PATH"
sed -i "s/pass=/pass="${p}"/3" $SCRIPT_PATH

user=admin
pass='pass1234'
```

Comment: we have two `sed`, a couple of `grep` piped to `awk`, etc. Better post the specific part that is not working along with some sample input. Otherwise it is a bit broad.

Comment: Post input and expected output and you can probably replace the script with a line.

Comment: the two `sed` : one for username and one for pass.  couple of `grep`:  its just to grep the value assigned to variable "username","password" and replace it in the `sed` line.  The output i expect is  the last two lines.. i.e user=  should replaced by user=admin   and pass=  should replaced by pass='pass1234' .

Comment: No, don't post comments to clarify. Instead, [edit] the question.

Comment: Am I reading it right? **A shell script updating itself with the values already present in same script**

Answer (score 1):

You should use `grep -m 1` to just get only the first match of username and password. And you can use `^user=` and `^pass=` to match the lines you want to change:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`/`basename $0`
username=admin
password='pass1234'

u="$(grep -m 1 'username' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"
p="$(grep -m 1 'password' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"

sed -i "s/^user=/user="${u}"/" "$SCRIPT_PATH"
sed -i "s/^pass=/pass="${p}"/" "$SCRIPT_PATH"

user=
pass=
```

Output is:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`/`basename $0`
username=admin
password='pass1234'

u="$(grep -m 1 'username' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"
p="$(grep -m 1 'password' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"

sed -i "s/^user=/user="${u}"/" "$SCRIPT_PATH"
sed -i "s/^pass=/pass="${p}"/" "$SCRIPT_PATH"

user=admin
pass='pass1234'
```

Comment: Thanks, learned. Just one more querry:  I used same `sed` after once more at the end in order to clear the values for user=admin and pass='pass1234' but with  `sed -i 's/^user=/user=/' "$SCRIPT_PATH"`  the values are appending and not getting reset.  please correct me..

Comment: OK. For learning can you clarrify why the carret ^user=  isn't enough to match it and replace it.

Comment: The `.*` matches everything to the end of the line, without it `user=` is replaced with `user=` (no change) and the rest of the line is unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

I used exactly what Nathan suggested, except I matched the ends of the line in the sed regex -  `user=$` and `admin=$`. That way, if the script is run more than once, you don't get "admin" and "'pass1234'" added again to `user=` and `admin=`

```
sed -i "s/user=$/user="${u}"/" "$SCRIPT_PATH"
sed -i "s/pass=$/pass="${p}"/" "$SCRIPT_PATH"
```

Comment: Yes that makes sense, i didn't mentioned that i want to reset the user= and pass=  again to the old.  I thought i could figure it out myself but struck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `sed` command instead of those two `sed` commands inside the script (it uses extended regex):

```
sed -nr 's@(user|pass)\w+=(.*)@s/^\1=$/\&\2/@p' "$SCRIPT_PATH" |sed -ri -f- "$SCRIPT_PATH"
```

---

Example:

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`/`basename $0`
username=admin
password='pass1234'

u="$(grep -m 1 'username' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"
p="$(grep -m 1 'password' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"

sed -nr 's@(user|pass)\w+=(.*)@s/^\1=$/\&\2/@p' "$SCRIPT_PATH" |sed -ri -f- "$SCRIPT_PATH"

user=
pass=
```

will be changed into:

```
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_PATH=`pwd`/`basename $0`
username=admin
password='pass1234'

u="$(grep -m 1 'username' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"
p="$(grep -m 1 'password' $SCRIPT_PATH | awk -F'=' '{ print $2 }')"

sed -nr 's@(user|pass)\w+=(.*)@s/^\1=$/\&\2/@p' "$SCRIPT_PATH" |sed -ri -f- "$SCRIPT_PATH"

user=admin
pass='pass1234'
```